Are the energy eigenfunctions, $\exp(-i\frac{E_n}{\hbar}t)$, orthogonal?
The energy eigenfunctions satisfy the following ODE:
$$i\hbar\,\partial_t\varphi_n(t)=E_n\varphi_n(t)$$
Its solution is $\varphi(t)=\exp(-i\frac{E_n}{\hbar}t)$. Since $\hat H=\hat E$ and due to $\hat H$ being hermitian, this makes me think that these eigenfunctions are orthogonal. The thing is $\hat H$ is hermitian for the inner product wrt position on all of $\mathbf R^3$, that is,
$$\int_{\mathbf R^3} \Psi^\ast(\mathbf r,t)\hat H \Psi(\mathbf r,t)\,\mathrm d^3\mathbf r=\int_{\mathbf R^3} [\hat H\Psi(\mathbf r,t)]^\ast \Psi(\mathbf r,t)\,\mathrm d^3\mathbf r,$$
so it doesn't make any sense to compute
$$\int_{\mathbf R^3} \varphi_n^\ast(t) \varphi_{n'}(t)\,\mathrm d^3\mathbf r$$

There are several  misconceptions here. First, proper Hamiltonian eigenfunctions are defined through $\hat{H} \varphi_E = E\varphi_E$ and being normalizable to 1. For usual $\hat{H}$s, $\varphi_E$ are functions of coordinates, and they do not need to depend on time, so they do not necessarily obey the first ODE. Only if the factor $e^{-i E t/\hbar}$ is included in them, then due to this factor, they obey the ODE, this is trivial. Your $\varphi(t)$ is just that time factor, it it is not the full eigenfunction. The eigenfunctions $\varphi_E$ are orthogonal since $\hat{H}$ is self-adjoint.

Second, it is not true that $\hat{H} = \hat{E}$, if you define $\hat{E} = i\hbar \partial_t$. These acts on different arguments of $\Psi$, one on coordinates and time, the second only on time, so they are different mathematical objects.

Your $\varphi_n, \varphi_{n'}$ (with different $E_n,E_{n'}$) are, in a sense, mathematically orthogonal functions regarding integrals over time, but this is not what people mean by orthogonal functions - this term refers to eigenfunctions $\varphi_E(\mathbf r)$, which are functions on the configuration space.

I can't really tell what you're trying to say. Please clarify your question. $e^{iEt/\hbar}$ is not usually an energy eigenstate by itself.

It needs to be multiplied by the spatial part as well.

Right now I'm in class, I'll continue editing the question later, hoping to fix this mess and the misunderstandings that derived from the original post, I wasn't explicit enough so it wasn't received well.

The Schrödinger equation is a PDE not an ODE. $e^{-it\frac{E_n}{\hbar}}$ is not the energy eigenfunction, but the eigenvalue of the time evolution operator.

What I meant is that when applying separation of variables ($\Psi(\mathbf r,t)=\Phi(\mathbf r)\varphi(t)$) to the Schrödinger equation it simplifies to solving two ODEs, $\hat H\Phi_n=E_n\Phi_n$ and $\hat E\varphi_n=E_n\varphi_n$, this last one being what we're discussing about. Regardless of that, are ${\varphi_n}$ orthogonal or not?

You are missing a time in the exponent.

@flippiefanus thx
